# IDE thinks I need to close a loop but it looks fine to me

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop

IDE says the Next for the

```
for i
```

right below the "Loop through folders commentis missing.

Here is my code.

```
Dim strVal As String

    'Loop through Folders
    For i As Integer = 0 To lbFolder.Items.Count - 1
        Dim iText As String = CStr(lbFolder.Items(i))
        Dim partPath As String = lblPath.Text + "\" + iText
        Dim pathNum As String = partPath + "\1900\"
        Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo(pathNum)
        Dim fileArr As FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles() ' Get a reference to each file in that directory.
        ' Display the names of the files.
        Dim xItem As FileInfo
        'loop through files

        For Each xItem In fileArr ' add to listbox
            lblFname.Text = xItem.ToString
            strVal = pathNum & xItem.ToString
            lbFiles.Items.Add(strVal)
        Next

        For j = 0 To lbFiles.Items.Count - 1 'read through files listbox
            Dim FileID, Sequence, Time, Lat, Longitude, Average, Channel As String
            'declaration of filestream to open file
            Dim sr As StreamReader
            'filestream object to open and read file
            Dim fs As FileStream
            Try
                'clearing listbox data toavoid confusion
                ListView1.Items.Clear()
                fs = New FileStream((lbFiles.Items.Item(j)), FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                'stream reader object to read streamed input
                sr = New StreamReader(fs)
                Dim itm As Object
                'reading line by line
                itm = sr.ReadLine
                While Not itm = Nothing
                    Dim split As String() = itm.Split(New [Char]() {","})
                    FileID = split(0)
                    Sequence = split(1)
                    Time = split(2)
                    Lat = split(3)
                    Longitude = split(4)
                    Average = split(5)
                    Channel = split(6)
                    With ListView1
                        .Items.Add(FileID)
                        .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Sequence)
                        .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Time)
                        .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Lat)
                        .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Longitude)
                        .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Average)
                        .Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Channel)
                    End With
                    itm = sr.ReadLine
                End While
                'close stream reader and filestrema object
                sr.Close()
                fs.Close()
            Catch ex As System.Exception
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Load Tool Data Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        Next j
        lbFiles.Items.Clear()
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am using visual studio, when I click on the for i it shows the closing next but when I run I get an error.

What am I missing?

Comment: it might be good to separate this into separate methods.

Comment: The nested loops are necessary as I am looking at files within folders within folders.

Comment: you can extract each loop into its own method.

Comment: Do you have anything above that piece of code?

Comment: @the_lotus Negative, this is the contents of a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Add **xItem** after the Next

   For Each xItem In fileArr ' add to listbox
        lblFname.Text = xItem.ToString
        strVal = pathNum & xItem.ToString
        lbFiles.Items.Add(strVal)
    Next xItem
```

Comment: Good thought but no dice.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.

Answer (score -1):

Restarted the IDE and everything ran with no errors.

Thanks all who responded